# Task 1 on projecteluler.net

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve first problem on this site, and since I am new to JS I have difficulties..

This is my code:

```
var a = function(){
  var array = [];
  for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0){
     array.push(i);
     document.write(array);
    };
  };
};
a();
```

It prints this: 33,53,5,63,5,6,9

I want find multiplies of 3 and 5, put them in array and then sum those numbers(i am not there yet).

What am I doing wrong and do I need to put loop inside function?

Comment: move you OR boolean operator and increase your loop .

Comment: It looks like you wanted to use `document.write` outside the loop. Move it outside the loop. `33,53,5,63,5,6,9` is just the concatenation of `[3][3,5][3,5,6][3,5,6,9]`, which is right.

Comment: you mean the element %3 == 0 || element %5 == 0 right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is finding all the multiples, but is showing them in a confused way.
Every time you find a new multiple you are printing a list with all the multiples you found so far, but your are not printing anything to separate one list from another.
So the string 33,53,5,63,5,6,9 is actually [3] [3,5] [3,5,6] [3,5,6,9], but put all together.